# Is it possible to update $jsonSchema in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema

I have created a collection and set additionalProperties to false. Is there any way to update its additionalProperties to true, add a property and then set it to false again? I want to put this process in a migration. The collection is not empty, therefore I cannot drop it and create it again.

Comment: can you post your collections and show us how you expect?

Comment: Problem solved using the resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55025621/mongodb-add-schema-for-existing-collection